# Is using fixed positioning the only way to prevent an element from triggering a scroll bar on the view port?

Tags: html, css

**Explanation:**

I have a page with a content div that will change height. When the div is small I'd like a nice gradient fade to the background color. As the div grows in height it should push the gradient further down until it is off the page.

**[Example Page](http://signdesignllc.net/fixed%20position.html)**

This example works properly, however I want to know if I can do this without using position:fixed on the gradient div. The reason that I don't want to use fixed positioning is because the above example looks strange on the iPad when you go to scroll the page up and down. Everything moves except the gradient so it makes the page look broken.

**Is there any way to structure my example without using fixed positioning?**

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adjust the height of elements and change `overflow` of `body` and `#content` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/R9uX8/)):

```
<div id="content">
    Content here. Use slider to adjust height.<br />
    <div id="slider"></div>
    This div <strong>should</strong> trigger a scrollbar on the window.
</div>
<div id="gradient">Gradient fade to body background. This div <strong>should not</strong> trigger a scrollbar on the window.</div>
```

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: Green;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16pt;
}
#slider {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#content {
    line-height: 100px;
    background-color: Red;
    overflow:auto;
    max-height:100%;
}
#gradient {
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    background: Orange;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't want the body overflow to be hidden. When the content overflows the body a scroll bar should appear... it's right there in my example.

Comment: @LuciferSam, yes, and it does for anything inside of `#content`, just like your example. If you would like something else, please show that in your example as well.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that at first glance. I'll award you the bounty when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Is using jQuery an option? if so, this may be one solution:

Whenever a scroll bar detected, check to see if it's caused because of the gradient or is it caused because of the content section. if it's because of the content keep the scrollbar if not, hide it.

```
// check to see if there is s scrollbar
if ($("body").height() > $(window).height()) {
    // ok there is a scrollbar, now lets see why there is a scrollbar:
    if ($("#content").height() > $(window).height()){
        // this is legit, do nothing
    }else{
       // the scroll bar is there because of the gradient, hide scroll bar
       $("body").css('overflow','hidden')
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I really want to know if I can do this using only HTML and CSS.